# problem with running ApiDemos in Eclipse

Tags: android

I imported ApiDemos from android-sdk folder using File/New/Project/Android Project/Create Project Existing Samples. When I tried to run any of them, I got this error:

[2011-06-09 10:03:34 - ApiDemos] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2011-06-09 10:03:34 - ApiDemos] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2011-06-09 10:03:34 - ApiDemos] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.example.android.apis' in a shell.

What I am supposed to do ? Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete existing version of Api Demos from emulator. Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications click on Api Demos and uninstall it.

And then re run Api Demos.

Hope this help!!!

Comment: When I run a particular java code (any Api demo code for instance ImageButton1.java). After this, when I run another java code (such as ImageSwitcher1.java), it just performs the old code. Of course before doing that, I uninstall old ApiDemos folder from the emulator. What's wrong then ?

Comment: If you found my answer useful, can you rate it or mark it as a best answer. Thanks.

Comment: Of course I can do that. How am I supposed to do that ? But, I still have problem with this. Either it is does not run in a different emulator, or It just performs same thing even though used different codes

Comment: If you are using eclipse. Try to clean your project and then re run it.

Comment: I did, but it does still show the same image even though I used different code :( Your help will be appreciated !

Comment: Okay, fixed it. Thanks for your answer though !

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the previous running of another android application. When running an Android application, Eclipse has to sign the application by the debug certificate. The existing cert is signed to the previous application and not allowed to install to the new application.

To resolve this problem, you have to uninstall the application by the adb uninstall command.
1. Open the command prompt
2. Go to the SDK directory \android-sdk\platform-tools\
3. Run the command adb uninstall com.android.packagename
4. After that, you can run the application in the Eclipse again.

[This works for me like a charm!! Magic!!](http://yp-appdev.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/resolved-please-execute-adb-uninstall.html)